# Recommendations for a SQL Server 2014 Database Administrators Course

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am after some personal recommendations for a SQL Server 2012 Database Administrators Course with exams.

- Exam 70-461: Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2014
- Exam 70-462: Administering Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Databases
- Exam 70-463: Implementing a Data Warehouse with Microsoft SQL Server 2014

I have done previous training with

•   **Training Camp** (FireBrand) this course they want £ 5,275 (6,330 Inc.
   VAT) this is too costly, yes I know they give Food and accommodation
   and exams. Good but currently out of my budget.

•   **Learning tree** this was designed to cover everybody was diluted a bit and the
   certification was their own.

•   **Parity Training** now have gone bust.

•   **StayAhead training** they mainly do Oracle but not bad.

I am after somewhere quality in that includes instructor lead training and exams the closer to Oxford (UK) the better.

I know this info will become out of date but will be useful as a guide for others, so will close in May 2014.

Comment: This question is nice for the research you've done but not a fit for this website as this information will be stale with the upcoming 2014 release of SQL Server.

Comment: fair point thought it would be due Q2/3 this year looks like it might be Q1 now

Comment: Almost all questions about IT "quickly become obsolete" - this industry in general is not as static as Mendeleev's Periodic Table or Newton's laws or Euclid's theorems. This " they quickly become obsolete" thing on this particular site does not sound completely right.

Comment: SQL2014 uses these same 3 exams.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend signing up for a trial of PluralSight. They have a TON of content, including courses specifically aimed at 70-461 and 70-462. I have been a few of their courses and they are excellent: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses#sql-server

Also, you may want to check out the MCM Readiness videos on Microsoft's site. They are a little out of date, but for things like index internals it won't matter a whole lot: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff977043.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another option is http://www.newhorizons.com/
They have an option where you can attend remotely. Good luck.

Here's a link to the first class you listed : [70-461](http://www.newhorizons.com/components/templates/CourseOutline.aspx?wt=a&GroupId=538&CourseKey=200005195)

Comment: Sorry wrong continent.